# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getheaders()

Tags: php

when I run my code I get this error

> PHP Warning:  log() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/x/websocket/server.php on line 2 PHP Fatal error: 
>   Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getheaders()

my code

```
<?php 
log("Handshaking...");
list($resource,$host,$origin) = getheaders($buffer);
$upgrade = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
           "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n" .
           "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
           "WebSocket-Origin: " . $origin . "\r\n" .
           "WebSocket-Location: ws://" . $host . $resource . "\r\n" .
           "\r\n";
$handshake = true;
socket_write($socket,$upgrade.chr(0),strlen($upgrade.chr(0)));
```

what's the wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php log is not for "Logs".

Try with `file_put_contents()`.

for `getheaders()` the correct syntax is `get_headers()`

Comment: you mean using file_put_contents("Handshaking..."); instead of log like that ?
i get this error PHP Warning:  file_put_contents() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Comment: No file_put_contents($filepath, $content); => http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php or you can use fopen(), fwrite() and fclose().